# Get URL for mediawiki page given the Title - programmatically in PHP

Tags: php, mediawiki

how can I get URL for an Article in MediaWiki given the title?

I want to create links to certain pages in the skin template **programmatically using PHP** right now I am doing this:

```
<a href="<?php $wgScriptPath ?>/index.php/Page_title">Page title</a>
```

Which is a bit too wordy, I'd like something

```
<?php page_link_by_title("Page_title") ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer above should work fine except for a minor typo (**Text** instead of Test).

```
$title = Title::newFromText("Title");
$title->getFullURL();
```

Comment: Note: Put require("/includes/Title.php") at the top of your file

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$title = Title::newFromText("Title");
$title->getFullURL();
```

That should create a new Title Class (svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classTitle.html), and retrieve the Full URL.