# How to get URL-encoded page title in MediaWiki PHP extension

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm developing a MediaWiki skin, and one of the elements I would like to use is the article URL-encoded title as the element ID or Class for styling purposes. I need help implementing this example:

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210230/get-url-for-mediawiki-page-given-the-title-programmatically-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are within the `execute` function of your skin, you ca access the [title object](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aTitle.php) like this:

```
$title = $this->data['skin']->getTitle();
```

Then you can get the URL enocoded title like this:

```
$URLEncodedTitle = $title->getPartialURL();
```

If you are in the `initPage` function, use

```
$title = $this->getTitle();
```